# Public Routes giving 403 in Spring Security 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement JWT Auth in my spring project. I've one end point which is `/auth/login`. When I try to make a api call, I'm getting error even though the particular route is specified inside `SecurityConfig`.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private EntryPoint point;

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationFilter filter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cor -> cor.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                        auth.requestMatchers("/home/*")
                                .authenticated()
                                .requestMatchers("/auth/login")
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**EntryPoint.java**

```
@Component
public class EntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("COMMENCE.....");
        response.setStatus(403);

    }
}
```

**JWTAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtHelper jwtHelper;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("FILTER.....");
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());

        String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (auth == null || !auth.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token");
            return;
        }

        String token = auth.split(" ")[1];
        String username = null;
        if (token == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token");
            return;
        }
        try {
            username = this.jwtHelper.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            Boolean validToken = this.jwtHelper.validateToken(token, userDetails);

            if (validToken) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Auth Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager manager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtHelper helper;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtResponse> login(@RequestBody JwtRequest request) {

        System.out.println(request.toString());
        this.doAuthenticate(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword());

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getEmail());
        String token = this.helper.generateToken(userDetails);

        JwtResponse response = new JwtResponse(token, userDetails.getUsername());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    private void doAuthenticate(String email, String password) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);
        try {
            manager.authenticate(authentication);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(" Invalid Username or Password  !!");
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BadCredentialsException.class)
    public String exceptionHandler() {
        return "Credentials Invalid !!";
    }

}
```

**Logs**

```
2023-07-05T20:04:49.012+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] com.auth.jwt.JwtApplication              : Starting JwtApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 15688 (/home/benzee/prince/boot/jwt-impl/jwt/target/classes started by benzee in /home/benzee/prince/boot/jwt-impl/jwt)
2023-07-05T20:04:49.017+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] com.auth.jwt.JwtApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-05T20:04:50.213+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2023-07-05T20:04:50.226+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-05T20:04:50.227+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2023-07-05T20:04:50.352+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-05T20:04:50.356+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1266 ms
2023-07-05T20:04:50.644+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [           main] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration@323f3c96}
2023-07-05T20:04:50.901+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@54755dd9, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@f1f7db2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2f4ba1ae, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e1b061, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6f798482, com.auth.jwt.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter@1daf3b44, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3762c4fc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3a8d467e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4462efe1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4b4ee511, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3a790e40, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@28ee7bee]
2023-07-05T20:04:51.068+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-05T20:04:51.083+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [           main] com.auth.jwt.JwtApplication              : Started JwtApplication in 2.578 seconds (process running for 2.896)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.300+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-07-05T20:04:56.300+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-07-05T20:04:56.301+05:30  INFO 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-07-05T20:04:56.308+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@54755dd9, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@f1f7db2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2f4ba1ae, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e1b061, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6f798482, com.auth.jwt.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter@1daf3b44, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3762c4fc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3a8d467e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4462efe1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4b4ee511, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3a790e40, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@28ee7bee]] (1/1)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.309+05:30 DEBUG 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /auth/login
2023-07-05T20:04:56.310+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.310+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.311+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.312+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.313+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.314+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-07-05T20:04:56.314+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JWTAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
FILTER.....
http://localhost:8081/auth/login
2023-07-05T20:04:56.315+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@54755dd9, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@f1f7db2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2f4ba1ae, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e1b061, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6f798482, com.auth.jwt.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter@1daf3b44, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3762c4fc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3a8d467e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4462efe1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4b4ee511, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3a790e40, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@28ee7bee]] (1/1)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 DEBUG 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.319+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-07-05T20:04:56.320+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JWTAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.320+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.320+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.321+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.321+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.321+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-07-05T20:04:56.322+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-07-05T20:04:56.323+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.323+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-07-05T20:04:56.324+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@183cafa]]
2023-07-05T20:04:56.335+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@183cafa]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@691c3b02
2023-07-05T20:04:56.337+05:30 TRACE 15688 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:358) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

COMMENCE.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from your filter. You should only check requests that have authorization headers.

Spring security will handle unauthenticated users if the request requires authentication or not.

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        
        if (auth != null && auth.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            String token = auth.split(" ")[1];
            String username = null;
            if (token == null) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token");
                return;
            }
            try {
                username = this.jwtHelper.getUsernameFromToken(token);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                Boolean validToken = this.jwtHelper.validateToken(token, userDetails);

                if (validToken) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
        }


        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```